# Which algorithm is used to update the training data (without retraining data) for Clustering (K-means)

Tags: machine-learning, k-means

There is a need to update the model without retraining data for k-means clustering algorithm. Please provide the name of any algorithm which is used to update the model for clustering type of problem.

There is a Stochastic Gradient Descent Algorithm for Classification and Regression. I have searched about Stochastic Gradient Descent for clustering algorithm but I did't get anything.

Comment: Not a `python` question - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Comment: In addition, your question is not entirely clear. What do you mean with updating the model without retraining data?

Answer (score 0):

The K-Means and SGD for classification and regression are fundamentally different algorithms. K-Means is unsupervised whereas SGD is supervised. The centroids for K-Means are relative all the other points, which make's up for their position and creates the grouping, whereas for SGD you're grouping/separating with functions that the algorithm itself is creating and updating (using Gradient Descent). I guess, however, you should be able to save the centroid positions along with each grouping of points and then rerun the algorithm whenever a new point is added.

Sklearn has `KMeans.cluster_centers_` attribute, which probably you could set before training.